# Python' Mechanize submission HTTP 404 error

Tags: python, mechanize

I want to make a python script using mechanize to log in as a specific user. Go to a specific page on that site, and fill out submit a form. I have successfully logged in, went to that page, filled out the form, but when I submit I get a weird error.

```
import mechanize
#from mechanize import ParseResponse, urlopen, urljoin

br=mechanize.Browser()
cj=mechanize.CookieJar()
br.set_cookiejar(cj)

br.set_handle_robots(False)
request=mechanize.Request("http://www.reddit.com/")
response=br.open("http://www.reddit.com/")
cj.extract_cookies(response, request)
request2=mechanize.Request("http://www.reddit.com/r/berkeley/about/flair/?  name=bezzerkeley")
cj.add_cookie_header(request2)
br.select_form(nr=1)
br["user"]="bezzerkeley"
br["passwd"]="xxxxxxx"
response2=br.submit()
cj.extract_cookies(response2, request2)
response3=br.open("http://www.reddit.com/r/berkeley/about/flair/?name=bezzerkeley")
request3=mechanize.Request("http://www.reddit.com/r/berkeley/about/flair/")
cj.extract_cookies(response3, request3)
cj.add_cookie_header(request3)
br.select_form(nr=8)
br["text"]="BOT TEST COMPLETE"
```

I xxxxed out the password for logging in. After I run this code and I do a br.submit() I get a HTTP Error 404: Not Found. If I physically go and submit this form in this way, the browser redirects me to the same page with the submitted info.

Extra information: when I do a print br.form after running the above code I get:

```
(POST http://www.reddit.com/post/flair application/x-www-form-urlencoded
  (HiddenControl(name=bezzerkeley) (readonly))
  (TextControl(text=BOT TEST COMPLETE))
  (TextControl(css_class=))
  (SubmitButtonControl((None)=) (readonly)))
```

I can provide more information if needed. Anybody know why I'm getting this error?

Comment: Typical reasons for such behavior are a) checking the user agent (on the server side) to prevent automated logins (→ set the user-agent manually) b) some java-script in effect when submitting the form (test login with js disabled).
Also in `request2`, there are two whitespaces?

Comment: @rumpel So I think b) is what's causing my problem. How do I test login with js disabled?

Comment: Disable it in your web-browser’s preferences (e.g. Firefox→settings→content→js)